# The JWS was signed by a public key the server does not support when trying to get certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, certbot

I am trying to get a certificate for my IIS server using Certbot. But I keep on getting this error:

```
[31mAn unexpected error occurred:[0m
[31mThe JWS was signed by a public key the server does not support :: sa.StorageAuthority.KeyBlocked timed out after 5004 ms[0m
```

The log file contains this:

```
acme.messages.Error: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:badPublicKey :: The JWS was signed by a public key the server does not support :: sa.StorageAuthority.KeyBlocked timed out after 5004 ms
2020-08-24 10:44:04,564:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:An unexpected error occurred:
2020-08-24 10:44:04,564:ERROR:certbot._internal.log:The JWS was signed by a public key the server does not support :: sa.StorageAuthority.KeyBlocked timed out after 5004 ms
```

Googling brought me nowhere... What a weird error...

Comment: Any luck solving this? I got the same thing today... Google is not too helpful here.

Comment: @PiotrKempa I think I just waited it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same error
This issue occur when letsencrypt server in the maintenance mode
because, when I try again to get certs I'he got the next error:

> acme.messages.Error: urn:acme:error:serverInternal :: The server experienced an internal error :: The service is down for maintenance or had an internal error. Check https://letsencrypt.status.io/ for more details.

Waiting for a few minutes I've got certs :)